# I put down the wrong city for POB on passport application

Tags: usa, passports, paperwork, us-citizens

I recently sent in my application and realized I put the wrong city on the POB line. It’s still the correct state, but I want to know if this will end up in my application being delayed/rejected?

Comment: Did the passport application require that you submit a copy of your US birth certificate?

Comment: Yes it did. I submitted the original and a photocopy.

Comment: Presuming that the birth certificate correctly shows your place of birth, I'd guess that the conflict between what you said (when you filled out the form) and what your birth certificate says is likely to lead to something other than prompt issuance of a passport, perhaps refusal or rejection, and is certainly likely to delay the process.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! I put down the city I currently live in so I don’t know how much that’ll affect it. I’ll just have to wait and see what the damage is.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to give an update: I didn’t have any issues and received my passport a couple days ago.

Comment: Which place of birth does it show?

Comment: Only the state is listed so I guess the city didn’t make much of a difference since it matched the one on my license.

Comment: I suggest that you add that into your answer.  Comments might get lost and this could be useful to others in the future.